# How to make File class use relative paths?

Tags: java, jar, filepath

I've been working on a project in java for a while now. I realized something terrible when trying to run a `.jar` of the project: It wasn't using relative paths anymore, instead it was searching in the "`C:\Users\Username\...`" directory for files.

I read that instead of using `new File("...");` you should use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("...");`

In a lot of places I used things like `new Sprite(new File("sprites\\sprite.png"));`, so it would **take a very long time** to go in and replace all of them.

I was hoping that there was something else I could do instead.
Like, is there any way to change the behavior of the File class?

Any tips? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I tried Duran Wesley Harris's idea of setting the `user.dir` property to the path of the folder with the `.jar`, which actually successfully changed where the files were being looked for. But the program still fails to load the files. I can actually copy the directory it's using into File Explorer and load the file that way, so it's mysterious to me why it can't load it in the program.

Note: The files are not inside the `.jar`, they are sitting next to it in the same folder. Also, the program works perfectly in the IDE (IntelliJ Idea).

Comment: Nope, if your resources are now embedded, you'll have to use getResource

Comment: you can achieve like this first get real path like getRealPath("/images"); after that create File filePath = new File(realPath); it would take less time.

Comment: It *was* using relative paths. However you were *executing* in `C:\Users\Username\...` somewhere, so that's where it looked.

Comment: Actually I was executing in H:\...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think you should take the time to refactor your code to use `xx.getResourceAsStream()` methods.

If you want to try and make a hacky solution you could try setting the `"user.dir"` property to the root of the jar with `System.setProperty()` or `java -Duser.dir=""` via command line.

Comment: Yes, other posts that mentioned changing the user.dir property said that it only really affects File creation but would not affect things like FileOutputStreams